# Is uploading/download executable files harmful in drupal?

Tags: security, files

In my site design, I have a field that is designed to hold an executable file (.exe, .bat, etc), for users to upload and download. I took pause as I was typing these extensions into the `Allowed file extensions` setting on the file field. Is this ok? What do I need to be aware of?

Comment: Probably not really a  problem unless your drupal is running on Windows.

Comment: this question is not related to Drupal, this is a question about keeping executable file in every where

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be just as safe / unsafe to do it in Wordpress or Joomla. Consider trying http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to make sure that your server is not configured to execute files of the given extensions in any way.

As a general precaution, you might also configure that file field to use the Private file system, which allows access to those files to be controlled by Drupal's permissioning system.